# Children's sci fi book from '90s/early 2000s that had a cover with two kids, and a ringed planet in the background

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I'm trying to find a book I read in grade school roughly 15 years ago. It probably was aimed at middle school/teens. I only remember small details from it.
The cover was in that painted pulp fiction style and it probably was from the '90s. I believe it had two siblings, a brother and a sister on the cover, running from something. In the background there was a planet with colorful rings in the sky.

I remember a couple scenes from it. One was something about the Sun going out, and I specifically remember the characters talking about how long it takes for the light, or lack thereof, to reach Earth. I feel like they were not on Earth at the time, maybe on the Moon or Mars. Another smaller detail I remember is that the protagonist noticed a Mac computer, but instead of the normal Apple logo, it was either another fruit, or an apple with no bite taken out of it.

That's all I can remember. I read it in a small school library no later than 2008 or 2009.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Sun going out is in *So You Want To Be A Wizard?* by Diane Duane. The computer with the apple emblem is in the third book in the series *High Wizardry.*  The series is known as the ["Young Wizards" series.](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40400-young-wizards)

Answer (score -1):

Could be “Songs of a Distant Earth by Arthur C Clarke.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct book, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. Do note, however, that the OP has already marked [sueelleker's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264794/122024) as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) -- as denoted by the green tick next to that answer -- which means the OP believes that answer is correct.